# Plot legend shows `NA` but dataset has no missing values - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

A scatter plot of cat heart weights using the `cats` dataset from the `MASS` package shows `NA` in the legend, but the dataset has no missing values.

```
data(cats, package = "MASS")

cats %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Hwt, y = 1, color = cut(Hwt, quantile(Hwt)))) +
  geom_jitter() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 3) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  labs(x = "Cat heart weight, g", 
       y = element_blank(),
       color = "Quantiles") +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("0-25%", "25-50%", "50-75%", "75-100%"))
```

[image]

Running `sum(is.na(cats$Hwt))` returns `[1] 0`.

Can anyone explain why the legend shows `NA` as one of the color labels, despite the dataset having no missing values?

Comment: There is an `NA` value in the interval variable - `anyNA(with(cats, cut(Hwt, quantile(Hwt))))`. You probably want to use `cut(Hwt, quantile(Hwt), include.lowest = TRUE)` so the minimum value is in range.

Comment: Brilliant! `anyNA(with(cats, cut(Hwt, quantile(Hwt), include.lowest = TRUE)))` returns `FALSE`.